# Необходимо построить крест. Для 3 условие работает, а для 5 условие не работает ставит лишние 0. Прошу помочь

Tags: java

```
public class Slash {
    public static void draw(int size) {
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int cell = 0; cell < size; cell++) {
                boolean left = (cell + row) % 2 == 0; /* добавить условие, по которому нужно определить ставить ли символ или нет. */
                boolean right = (cell + row) == size - 1; /* добавить условие, что нужно ставить элемент в правый угол. */
                if (left) {
                    System.out.print("0");
                } else if (right) {
                    System.out.print("0");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Draw by 3");
        draw(3);
        System.out.println("Draw by 5");
        draw(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так попробуйте

```
  for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        for (int cell = 0; cell < size; cell++) {
            boolean left = cell == row; /* добавить условие, по которому нужно определить ставить ли символ или нет. */
            boolean right = row == size - cell - 1; /* добавить условие, что нужно ставить элемент в правый угол. */
            if (left || right) {
                System.out.print("0");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Работает спасибо)